# How to print regex expression in awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file with hundreds of lines with contents that looks like this:

```
6281316
6281315
6281317
```

I simply want to use awk to transform them into regex expression so I could use it later.

```
/6281316/
/6281315/
/6281317/
```

howerver, when I run:

```
awk '{print "/"$1"/"}' file.txt
```

it give back

```
/6281316
/6281315
/6281317
```

Does anybody could point out where I went wrong?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your command. Your file has **windows formatting**. Convert the file to unix format using `dos2unix` and re-run the command.

Comment: wow, thanks. You guess right, I copied the file from a windows and dos2unix does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your command works for me without any issue. Maybe try a sed solution:

```
sed 's/^/\//;s/$/\//' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this could also work. But I'm accepting the other answer because it is apparently the root of my problem.